# Anchor links not working in WordPress 4.0

Tags: html, anchor

I'm having an issue I am absolutely stumped by. I've looked through people who have had a similar problem, and none the solutions have worked.

The anchor links are not working on this page:
http://www.movenjfit.com/new/personal-training-gym-hoboken/

I have added anchor links to the drop down menu. I have also tried just creating anchor links on an external page. I've tried disabling all the plugins and using the 2014 theme, so it's just a bare bones WordPress site. No luck!

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, the URL changes ?

Comment: Are you talking about What we do and why we do it?\

Answer (score 3):

Remove the trailing slash from your anchor links.